# Change worksheet tab size in Numbers on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, numbers

Is there any way of change worksheet tab size in Numbers on Mac? Maybe width of tab can depend on width of word inside (like in Excel)?

Comment: Any luck on this?  My guess is that there is no way, but I'm still hoping.

Comment: IMO Numbers has too many limitations in general.  Is it too much to grab a copy of Office 2011 for Mac?

Comment: My experience is that it changes the size after you save it and close it. At least for me, when I reopen the file, the size is just like the size of the word inside